# Co-assigning python variables works different with integers and sets. Why?

Tags: python

Suppose I co-assign two python variables to zero:

```
>>> x = y = 0
```

When I now assign to one value it changes independently of the other:

```
>>> y = 2
>>> x
0
>>> y
2
```

Now suppose I co-assign two python variables to an empty set:

```
>>> a = b = set([])
```

When I now add to one set, it changes the value of the other. Why?

```
>>> b.add(2)
>>> a
set([2])
>>> b
set([2])
```

Comment: Immutable vs mutable.

Comment: Assuming you are on the C implementation of python, compare `id(a)` with `id(b)`, does that give you a clue?

Answer (score 1):

As commments to OP answer are just implicit clues I am making them explicit:

```
y = 0
x = y
```

Names `x` and `y` reference the same int object with `0` value.

`int` objects are immutable. As you can't alter them, it actually doesn't
matter what object with zero value you are pointing to, if there were several.

When you assign `y` again with

```
y = 2
```

`y` now refers to a different int object with value `2`.
`x` still refers to the old 0 value object.

If you consider mutable types like sets,

```
b = set()
a = b
```

`a` and `b` reference the same empty set object.
If you change the set object with an in-place assignment, or using an object method that changes it in-place, the object remains the same (but with its value content changed).
So you can see the changed object either through `a` or through `b`.

However, to compare apples with apples and follow the `int` sample, if you make

```
b = set() # a new empty set
```

`b` becomes a new different set empty object, while `a` still references the original.

```
>>> a = set()
>>> b = a
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
>>> b = set()
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>>
```

So behaviour is actually the same in both cases. But in int case you can't make changes to the object value.